# Validate radio buttons with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

How do I validate these two radio buttons using jQuery? One button should be checked:

```
<input type="radio" name="muuttuminen" value="Kylla" /> Kyllä
<input type="radio" name="muuttuminen" value="Ei"/>Ei
```

I know how to validate regular text input fields, but I'm wondering about this one.

```
     $(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(){
 //validation part
          var dataString = $('#service-test').serialize();
          //alert (dataString);return false;
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../quiz.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "text",
        error: function(){ alert ('Nyt jotakin meni kyllä pahemman kerran pieleen. Yritä uudelleen?');
     },
        success: 
        function(data) {
     $("#resultcontainer").html(data);
     $("#service-test").hide();

       }

      });
      return false;

        });
      });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:checked` selector and the `length` property:

```
    $(".submit").click(function() {
       if ($('input[name="muuttuminen"]:checked').length == 0) {
         alert('please...');
         return false; } 
          else {
          $.ajax({
           //...
         })
       }
       return false;
    });
```

Comment: The part I need, doesn't work for me. I added the full script to my code.

Comment: Added ==0 to length and a return false so the script won't continue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like give below.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tCXgg/3/)**

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {     
      if($('input[type=radio][name=muuttuminen]:checked').length == 0)
      {
         alert("Please select atleast one");
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
          alert("radio button selected value: ");
      }      
    });
});
```

Comment: You have missed `''` for the input, and space between the `:checked` and `input` selector should be removed.

Comment: Tahnks Raminson, so nice of you.

Comment: That page could not be opened, the quotes were missing in the selector and I updated the code. Make sure you have latest code.

Comment: I have the latest, and it just refreshes the page.

Comment: I am still unable to open this page, can you put it on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry @Christian Nikkanen for late reply, I have given live link of working sample

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QKHwn/1/):

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
        var atLeastOneChecked = false;

        $("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
                atLeastOneChecked = true;
            }
        });

        if (!atLeastOneChecked) {
            $("#checked").text("Check one");
        } else {
            $("#checked").text("One is checked");
        }
    });
});​
```

This is a generalised example that will check ALL radio buttons on the page, you might not want this so it may be worth putting your radio buttons in a group and checking the group this way:

```
$("#inputgroup").find("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    // do the validation here
});
```

The code to check these two specific buttons would be:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=muuttuminen]").each(function() {
    // do the validation here
});
```

Comment: I only want to check these two buttons.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Edited answer and jsFiddle for your specific radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty incomplete but something like

```
var valid = false;

$('#yourForm').find(':input:radio').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
        valid = true;
});

if(!valid)
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [checked pseudo-class](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked). Here is a fiddle of what you might use for form submission.
http://jsfiddle.net/WhPcj/

Comment: And how is this supposed to work on a live website? This tells me what button is checked.

Comment: I'm sorry, when I gave this answer, you hadn't updated your post, this is merely to get the value of the checked button, you can then do any type of operation, not just an alert. I use this on a live web application I maintain to craft my serialized output. Something like `data.checkBox = $("input[name='myCheckBox']:checked").val()`, then I pass that to backend PHP.

Comment: Well, here's a brief of my backend: Check the answers, show the paragraphs if conditions match, then calculate the possible costs of the selections, and pass them back to the script, show them on a div.

Comment: Well you could just check to see if the value exists on the backend. Pretty much in pseudocode, `if(data.checkBox=="Kylla"){ //do whatever } else { //do other condition }`

Comment: The value exists, I know that. My problem is that the radios I have to validate are necessary for the backend to return the correct result.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding what you're saying. Why will my method not work?